# Como eu passo um ID de uma lista para um propriedade na qual usarei para enviar para outra view dinâmicamente?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

**Estou tentando passar o ID de uma lista de respositorio para outra view de forma dinâmica porém não consigo por o ID dentro da propriedade IdRepositorio**

```
public class InicioViewModel:BaseViewModel
{        
    private ObservableCollection<Repositorio> repositorio;
    public ObservableCollection<Repositorio> Repositorio 
    { 
        get { return repositorio; }
        set 
        {
            repositorio = value;
        }
    }

    private int _IdRepositorio;
    public int IdRepositorio
    {
        get { return _IdRepositorio; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _IdRepositorio, value); }
    }

    public Command BtnListaRepo { get; set; }
    public Command<object>BtnAbrirJanelaPesquisa { get; set; }


    public InicioViewModel()
    {
       
        BtnAbrirJanelaPesquisa = new Command<object>(AbrirJanelaPesquisaCommand);
        repositorio = new ObservableCollection<Repositorio>();
        var listaRepositorios = ListaRepoCommand();
        
        
    }
    public async Task ListaRepoCommand()
    {
      
        foreach (var item in await App.conexaoApi.RepositoriosGetAsync())//listar repositorio
        {
            Repositorio.Add(new Repositorio
            {
                ID = item.ID,
                NomeExibicao = item.NomeExibicao,
               
            });
     
        }
        
    }
    public async void AbrirJanelaPesquisaCommand(object rep )
    {

        
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new AppNeutron.Views.JanelaPesquisa(IdRepositorio));
    }
}
```

}

*Essa é  a ViewModel da minha View Inicio, nela eu criei dois métodos, onde, ListaRepoCommand() lista os repositórios da minha API usando ID e NomeExibicaoe o AbrirJanelaPesquisaCommand(object rep ) envia a o repositório através do IdRepositorio porém estou falhando colocar o ID dentro da propriedade IdRepositorio*

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodel:InicioViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Repositorio}" RowHeight="60" x:Name="listViewRepo">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command= "{Binding Path=BindingContext.BtnAbrirJanelaPesquisa, Source={x:Reference listViewRepo } }" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                <Label Text="{Binding ID}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15" TextColor="black"/>
                                <Label  Text="{Binding NomeExibicao}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="15" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

*Está é minha View Inicio onde eu estou fazendo o Binding do meu mvvm. Por fim, gostaria muito de saber onde estou errando e porque não consigo fazer a conexão do ID com a propriedade IdRepositorio.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentar alterar a chamada para assim:

```
IdRepositorio = ((Repositorio)rep).ID;
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new 
AppNeutron.Views.JanelaPesquisa(IdRepositorio));
```

No seu código, o parâmetro rep é passado para o método AbrirJanelaPesquisaCommand ao clicar em um item na lista, você pode usar esse parâmetro para definir o valor da propriedade IdRepositorio. Se ajudar, marca como resolvido.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Luiz. Estava a muito tempo nessa task e o senior quase nunca me ajuda e quando ajuda faz sem vontade. Muito obrigado de verdade. Eu só n entendi o que está acontecendo aqui: ((Repositorio)rep).ID;